# Creating a default model to knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm creating a new a default object with knockout JS

```
self.PatientModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.PatientId = ko.observable(data.PatientId||0),
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name||""),
    self.LastName = ko.observable(data.LastName||"Smith")
}
```

but when i do :

```
self.Patient(new self.PatientModel());
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PatientId' of undefined
```

I now that data is null, but i want a a default value like with lastname

I found http://kostructures.com/ko.Model/ but i need a simplest solution

Thanks

Comment: You could just add `data = data || {};` right inside you're function

Comment: great! thanks, it was simple, i'm tired...

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that data has at least something before you try to access properties on it. You could solve it like this:

```
self.PatientModel = function(data) {
    data = data || {PatientId: 0, Name: "", LastName: "Smith"}
    var self = this;
    self.PatientId = ko.observable(data.PatientId);
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.LastName = ko.observable(data.LastName);
}
```

Or another solution, close to what you had:

```
self.PatientModel = function(data) {
    data = data || {};
    var self = this;
    self.PatientId = ko.observable(data.PatientId||0),
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name||""),
    self.LastName = ko.observable(data.LastName||"Smith")
}
```